# React app: bundle js before custom js files at npm run start

Tags: reactjs

It is usually like this when i use npm run start in react app

```js
<script src=".js/custom.js"></script> //Here
<script src="./static/js/2.3df1cc2f.chunk.js"></script>
<script src="./static/js/main.f26c4128.chunk.js"></script>
```

But i want the chunk before my custom js file like

```js
<script src="./static/js/2.3df1cc2f.chunk.js"></script>
<script src="./static/js/main.f26c4128.chunk.js"></script>
<script src=".js/custom.js"></script> //Here
```

How can I achieve that any help.

Comment: What's in your custom js file? Why not include is as a module inside the rest of your source code?

Comment: its a third party libarary for animation if it is above bundle js animation wont show

Comment: which library is it? maybe there is an npm package for it